# lightbox2 , image inside lightbox linkable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

Is it possible using the Lightbox2 script from
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

to make the images inside a "lightbox", a url.

Lets say i would open a lightbox, and then click on the image inside it, that image could bring me to a new page or some other link.

Tried to look for this more than an hour on google but couldn't find anything with it !

If anyone has any ideas, let me know !

thanks

Comment: does it have to be Lightbox2 or open to alternatives ?

Comment: possibly Lightbox2, but i could check for other sources. I just like how lighbox2 is easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to alternatives, I suggest you try Fancybox
http://fancybox.net/